# VSCODE error: mysql.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-code

I have used Windows VSCode to set this way to connect to mysql, but can't solve the error :No such file or directory mysql.h, test.cpp is under the same class as json file.
c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/**",
          "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\include"
        ],
        "defines": [
          "_DEBUG",
          "UNICODE",
          "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "D:\\fix\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
  }
```

settings.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "array": "cpp",
        "atomic": "cpp",
        "bit": "cpp",
        "*.tcc": "cpp",
        "cctype": "cpp",
        "clocale": "cpp",
        "cmath": "cpp",
        "compare": "cpp",
        "concepts": "cpp",
        "cstdarg": "cpp",
        "cstddef": "cpp",
        "cstdint": "cpp",
        "cstdio": "cpp",
        "cstdlib": "cpp",
        "cstring": "cpp",
        "cwchar": "cpp",
        "cwctype": "cpp",
        "deque": "cpp",
        "string": "cpp",
        "unordered_map": "cpp",
        "vector": "cpp",
        "exception": "cpp",
        "algorithm": "cpp",
        "functional": "cpp",
        "iterator": "cpp",
        "memory": "cpp",
        "memory_resource": "cpp",
        "numeric": "cpp",
        "random": "cpp",
        "string_view": "cpp",
        "system_error": "cpp",
        "tuple": "cpp",
        "type_traits": "cpp",
        "utility": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp",
        "iosfwd": "cpp",
        "istream": "cpp",
        "limits": "cpp",
        "new": "cpp",
        "numbers": "cpp",
        "stdexcept": "cpp",
        "streambuf": "cpp",
        "typeinfo": "cpp"
    }
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe 生成活动文件",
        "command": "D:\\fix\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": 
        [
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "-I",
          "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\include",
          "-L",
          "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\lib"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
          "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": " D:\\fix\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
      }
    ]
  }
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>

using namespace std;
int main (){
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    // q1();
    MYSQL conn;
    int res;
    mysql_init(&conn);
 
    
   
    if (mysql_real_connect(&conn, "127.0.0.1", "root", "pswd", "test", 0, NULL, CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS)) //"root":11,:123  "test":11
    {
        printf("connect success!\n");
        res = mysql_query(&conn, "insert into test values('user','123456')");
        if (res)
        {
            printf("error\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("OK\n");
        }
        mysql_close(&conn);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("connect error!\n"); 
        cout << mysql_error(&conn) << endl;
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

I try many methods online but can't solve my problem at all,can anyone help me?

Comment: Does `C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\include` contain `mysql.h`? Are you sure that you are not using code-runner?